# SkelJS - Differents rows offsets, one for each specific breakpoints

Tags: javascript, html, responsive-design, mobile-website, skel

I'm starting to use Skel for building responsive webdesigns.

I want to set alternative units width for my differents breakpoints (layouts)

Look at this code:

```
<div class="-1u 10u -1u">
     <p> Some text ipsum</p>
</div>
```

So here, we have a offset of 1u on each side of the row.
What i want to do, is to set specific offsets for each breakpoints i'm using (wide, medium, small, xxsmal).

When i dont need offsets, i do like this:

```
<div class="2u 6u(medium) 12u(small)">
     <p> Some text ipsum</p>
</div>
```

But with offsets it just dont work the way i'm expecting, any help would be very usefull for me.

I maybe didnt totally understood how SkelJS is working, so excuse me if the answer is in the doc.
Thanks in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagine you want in wide mode: 3 offsets + 6 units + new line

Then in medium: 2 offsets + 8 units + new line

And in small: 12 units:

You will write:

```
<div class="-3u(wide) 6u$(wide) -2u(medium) 8u$(medium) 12u(small)">
</div>
```

Comment: What is the dollar sign?

Comment: I guess it means end-of-line, like in a regular expression.

Comment: I figured it would prevent another div to be set on the same line. 2x6u would be next to each other, 2x6u$ would set the second under the first